# JavaScript Math.round bug in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, opera

This JavaScript demonstrates a bug in IE that is driving me nuts right now:

```
var y = 6044629098073143; // this exact integer easily fits into an IEEE double
document.write(y + " " + Math.round(y)+"<br><br>");
```

The output in IE 8 (and Opera 12.02) shows that `Math.round` is off by 1:

```
6044629098073143 6044629098073144
```

Output in Firefox, Chrome and Safari is correct.

What on earth is going on here with IE and Opera?

Comment: Maybe really an IE bug? See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/number.html#round

Comment: According to [ECMA-262](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.2.15), `If x is already an integer, the result is x`. However, since `Math.round(6044629098073144)` returns the correct value in IE, and it keeps oscillating between correct and +1 as you increase the number (even numbers are static, odd are incremented by one), I suspect you have reached the limit of contiguous javascript integers.

Comment: We have not reached the limit of contiguous javascript integers (since all integers <= 2^53 can be represented exactly, and as demonstrated by the 'y' output directly).

Comment: For the record, in IE the largest contiguous integer that `Math.round` returns without modification is 4503599627370496, which is 2^52, after that it goes by twos, indicating that there is an operation that is dropping one bit of precision since contiguous integers should go to 2^53. So definitely a bug.

Comment: Just noticed that ECMA-262 also says "The value of Math.round(x) is the same as the value of Math.floor(x+0.5)", so perhaps that's where the missing bit is going, since `Math.floor(y + 0.5)` has exactly the same behaviour in IE. Note that the continguous limit for non–integers from `Math.round` is 2^52 anyway. So maybe not a bug but a difference of interpretation of the spec.

Comment: @RobG The note is informative, and hence there is no ambiguity in the spec here. It's a bug in IE/Opera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've confirmed RobG's comments: All integers below 2^52 (4503599627370496) appear to round correctly in all browsers.  Integers higher than this round UP to an EVEN number in IE/Opera with Math.round (whereas other browsers round correctly).

As RobG mentioned, it is likely that IE and Opera implement Math.round(x) as Math.floor(x + 0.5), which leads to these results since adding 0.5 to a value > 2^52 yields an imprecise result.  A smarter implementation of round() would use the FPU's native rounding support (IE and Opera developers, please take note and fix!)

In the meantime, this workaround should work:

```
// workaround for IE and Opera's brain-dead Math.round() implementation
if (y < 4503599627370496) // 2^52
{
  y = Math.round(y);
}
// else 'y' is already an integer
```

Comment: Using the native FPU adds extra per-platform code into the implementation (and many default/only to round-to-zero, not round-to-positive-infinity), esp. when you need a codepath for when there's no FPU at all.

Answer (score 1):

In Opera an IE, the biggest Integer value guaranteed to work is 4503599627370496 (2^52) as stated by RobG in the comments above.

Interestingly, this also applies to floating point values in some parts.
For numbers bigger than that, also floating point numbers loose their accuracy.
As you see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Internal_representation), doubles have a mantissa with an accuracy of 52 bits. This means, that for all numbers greater than 4503599627370496, the last digit(s) will be trimmed, as the mantissa is always aligned with the most significant bits (MSB) of the represented number.

Typed in Opera's console:

```
//This works
>>> 4503599627370494.5 //Consumes 53 bits
4503599627370494.5
>>> 4503599627370495.5 //Consumes 53 bits
4503599627370495.5
//This works no more, the last bit is now needed
>>> 4503599627370496.5 //Consumes 54 bits
4503599627370496
```

And this loss in accuracy explains why these browsers don't have an accurate representation of the number, the last bit is simply rounded away. Also see [Machine_epsilon.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon)
Though, what you can conclude from this observation, is that the integers shown in the questions are definitely converted into doubles.